# Have a problem with speed of recorded video from Webcam

Tags: c#, aforge, video-recording

I want to recording a video from Webcam here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
            if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                int h = pic.Image.Height;
                int w = pic.Image.Width;
                FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.Default);
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
   
            }
        }
```

when i use other Webcam it come out with normally speed
but when i use a webcam that come with my laptop the speed of recorded video it's more faster than normal
Any Help?

Comment: What is `FileWriter.Open` also what is this parameter `25`, my complete guess, is that could be fps. Anyway, this question needs work, its missing some vital information

Comment: If it appears like timelaps then it is probably that your camera is sending less fps than you configure the video file to be. For example: You tell the video to be 25 fps but the camera makes only 5 fps, then you'll perceive a 5x "speedup" ( 5 seconds in real will make 1 second video).